# How to solve 'closure' to vector of type 'character' problem caused by using source() in R package?

Tags: r, function, package, closures

I am creating an R package. One of my functions is using GSEA R code to do the pathway enrichment analysis.

I use the following R code to call the function as the GSEA R code suggested:

```
source(GSEA.program.location, verbose=F, max.deparse.length=9999).
```

However, I got an error:

```
error in source(GSEA.program.location, verbose=F, max.deparse.length=9999):
    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'".
```

I googled but failed to find a suitable solution.

Comment: The first thing to check is what `GSEA.program.location` is. Are you sure that it is a vector of type `character`, not a function? Try `str(GSEA.program.location)` to makes sure.

Comment: Yes, it should be the location of GSEA r code. I saved the file as in extdata folder as shown below: >str(GSEA.program.location)
 chr "/ihome/ywang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mypackage/extdata/GSEA.1.0.R"

Comment: And you did that `str()` check right before this `source()` call? Because that doesn't seem to match up with what the error message is saying. Maybe there is some code in between that is changing the value of the `GSEA.program.location` variable. It's not really possible to help further without a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)